# Post a comment with facebook rest API in C++

Tags: c++, rest, facebook-graph-api

I am using cpr library from [here](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr). 
Currently my response looks like:

```
auto response = cpr::Post(
            cpr::Url{
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/feed?message=blablabla&access_token="+accToken}
```

When I open Graph API explorer,the comment is added just fine but it is not reflected. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Mani - I saw you added "*Thanks for your actionables. :)*" to the end of this question. Greetings and thanks [should be **removed** from posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/1364007), not added. I've since removed it from the question.

Comment: @WaiHaLee its ok...I will take care of it :)

Comment: @Mani - just to clarify, I didn't mean you should go back and only remove thanks from posts as that's probably going to be rejected as a trivial edit. Once you have 2000 reputation you'll be able to edit posts without review (or getting +2 for each edit).

Comment: @WaiHaLee What you expect from me...?

Comment: @Mani - maybe read the link I posted above. Basically, when making an edit it should be substantial. The [help centre page on editing posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) might be worth a read.

Comment: Thanks @WaiHaLee I respect  your suggestion

Comment: What do you mean when you say the comment is not "reflected"?